# Add icon within input field using Core MVC and unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

My code works fine for bordering the input box red or green based on valid/error state, however how would I get an exclamation icon (font awesome?) to display on the inside right of the field? I am Using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>How many?</p>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Quantity" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes, download dependency at NuGet of awesome font icons and this is exclamation <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> , put it at the error message

Comment: @JordiJordi I don't know what you mean, put it at the error message. I don't set any specific error messages. They are generic, handled by MVC.

Comment: you say you are using unobtrusive, at server side, you have de viewModel with atributes and annotations, example Required, you can add the ErrorMessage to show with unobtrusive, for example:  [Required(ErrorMessage ="textYouWantANDExclamationIcon")]

Comment: Style your elements, for example using a css `::after` psuedo selector (the error message placeholder has `class="field-validation-error"` if its invalid)